# Calculate pairwise similarity of strings in column using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

If I have a `df` with the following columns and rows:

| row | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | This sentence is very similar to the next sentence |
| 2 | This sentence is not very similar to the next sentence |
| 3 | You can't sneeze with your eyes opened |
| ... | ... |

How can I apply a function that check for every value in the `text` column whether there is a similar sentence in another row of that column? What I want to do is to then remove rows in which the value of the `text` column is too similar. For example, how can I ensure that no cell in the column is more than 30, 40, or 80% similar to another string in that same column?

What I want to end up with is the following:

| row | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | This sentence is very similar to the next sentence |
| 3 | You can't sneeze with your eyes opened |
| ... | ... |

Comment: Could you please specify your question? Do you want to know how to determine similarity of Strings or how to apply this along the whole dataframe for every combination of rows? Alsow, how do you want to filter the similarity? lets say row 1 and 2 have a similarity of 80% which is way to high. do you remove both 1 and 2 or just one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution and slow on a large data.frame, but you can use `stringdist::stringsim`. This can compare text and returns different similarity measures (see the `method` argument). So given your data:

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~row, ~text,
  1,    "This sentence is very similar to the next sentence",
  2,    "This sentence is not very similar to the next sentence",
  3,    "You can't sneeze with your eyes opened"
)


stringdist::stringsim(df$text[1], df$text)
#> [1] 1.0000000 0.9259259 0.2800000
```

We can wrap this in a function to compare every text with all texts that came before and return a logical vector.

```r
library(dplyr)
find_dup <- function(string, thres) {
  purrr::map_lgl(seq_along(string), function(i) {
    sim <- stringdist::stringsim(string[i], string[0:(i - 1)])
    any(sim > thres)
  })
}
```

Using `mutate` you can check if the result is correct and then remove the duplicated entries with `filter()`:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(dup = find_dup(text, 0.8))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>     row text                                                   dup  
#>   <dbl> <chr>                                                  <lgl>
#> 1     1 This sentence is very similar to the next sentence     FALSE
#> 2     2 This sentence is not very similar to the next sentence TRUE 
#> 3     3 You can't sneeze with your eyes opened                 FALSE

df %>% 
  filter(!find_dup(text, 0.8))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>     row text                                              
#>   <dbl> <chr>                                             
#> 1     1 This sentence is very similar to the next sentence
#> 2     3 You can't sneeze with your eyes opened
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution based on calculating the Levenshtein distance between strings using the `levenshteinSim` function from the `RecordLinkage` package, which is reasonably fast:

```r
library(RecordLinkage)

exclude_similar <- function(text, similarity = 0.8) {
  
 sim_mat <- asplit(outer(text, text, levenshteinSim), 1)
 exclude <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(sim_mat), function(x) {
         y <- which(sim_mat[[x]] > similarity)
         y[y > x]
         }
        ))
 answer <- rep(TRUE, length(text))
 answer[exclude] <- FALSE
 return(answer)
}
```

You would use the function like this:

```r
df[exclude_similar(df$text, similarity = 0.8), ]
#>   row                                               text
#> 1   1 This sentence is very similar to the next sentence
#> 3   3             You can't sneeze with your eyes opened

df[exclude_similar(df$text, similarity = 0.1), ]
#>   row                                               text
#> 1   1 This sentence is very similar to the next sentence

df[exclude_similar(df$text, similarity = 0.95), ]
#>   row                                                   text
#> 1   1     This sentence is very similar to the next sentence
#> 2   2 This sentence is not very similar to the next sentence
#> 3   3                 You can't sneeze with your eyes opened
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Data used**

```r
df <- read.table(text = "row    text
1   \"This sentence is very similar to the next sentence\"
2   \"This sentence is not very similar to the next sentence\"
3   \"You can't sneeze with your eyes opened\"", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Cool approach! FYI: my function is between 5-8 times faster depending on the method I use inside of stringsim. I used `stringr::sentences` as a test case since the example here is so short. What likely makes both functions slow is the iteration but I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: @JBGruber good to know. Using `outer` in my case is comparing n^2 pairs of strings, while you are comparing (1/2 n^2 - n ) strings, which is more efficient. I guess it's convenience versus speed, but your answer got my vote.